# Add checkbox without caption cell

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to find old posts related to this same issue but couldn't find a solution which would fit to my code.

I'm trying to add checkboxes to Excel sheet every time I add new row to sheet. Checkbox should be added when date is added to range A11:A80.
However with my current code checkbox is added but caption is always added which I don't want.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A11:A80")) Is Nothing Then
Call checkbox
End If
End Sub


Sub checkbox()

    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim oCheckBox As checkbox
    Dim r As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Set wsTarget = ActiveSheet
    Set r = wsTarget.Range("A11:A80")
    
    With wsTarget
    For Each cell In r
        If Weekday(cell, vbMonday) > 5 Then

        Else
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
            .CheckBoxes.Add Left:=cell.Offset(0, 9).Left, Top:=cell.Offset(0, 9).Top, Width:=60, Height:=15
            
        End If
        End If
        Next cell
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]
Another issue is that checkbox is not added when I modify cell in range A11:A80, it only works when I manually run the macro

All the help is much appreciated!
Thank you in advance

Comment: A Yes/No drop-down using data validation would be much easier to manage and not prone to checkboxes shifting after sorting etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Setting the label is easy. All you have to do is to assign the created Checkbox to a variable and work with that:

```
cb As CheckBox
Set cb = .CheckBoxes.Add(Left:=cell.Offset(0, 9).Left, Top:=cell.Offset(0, 9).Top, Width:=60, Height:=15)
cb.Caption = ""
```

(2) I assume that your `Worksheet_Change`-event is in the wrong place, it needs to be in the Worksheet-Module. I see no other reason why it is not triggered

(3) If you call your checkbox-routine multiple times, it will created multiple checkboxes for every row. I would suggest that you set a name for every checkbox containing the row number and test before adding a new checkbox if it already exists.

```
Dim cbName As String, cb As CheckBox
cbName = "checkBox_" & cell.Address
                                
On Error Resume Next
Set cb = Nothing
Set cb = .CheckBoxes(cbName)
On Error GoTo 0

If cb Is Nothing Then
    Set cb = .CheckBoxes.Add(Left:=cell.Offset(0, 9).Left, Top:=cell.Offset(0, 9).Top, Width:=60, Height:=15)
    cb.Caption = ""
    cb.Name = cbName
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Use selection checkbox to modify properties.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A11:A80")) Is Nothing Then
        Call checkbox
    End If
End Sub


Sub checkbox()
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim oCheckBox As checkbox
    Dim r As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Set wsTarget = ActiveSheet
    Set r = wsTarget.Range("A11:A80")
    
    With wsTarget
    For Each cell In r
        If Weekday(cell, vbMonday) > 5 Then

        Else
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
            ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(cell.Offset(0, 9).Left, cell.Offset(0, 9).Top, 60, 15).Select
            With Selection
                .Caption = "Test caption name"
                .Value = xlOn 'xlOff to default
            End With
            
        End If
        End If
        Next cell
    End With

End Sub
```